# Celery worker not restarting after completing max task per child

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I've set max-task-per-child for celery worker with default concurrency and `pool=prefork` it still won't restart and release memory like it does on manually stopping and starting

celery report

```
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME: datetime.timedelta(days=31)
USE_X_SENDFILE: False
SERVER_NAME: None
APPLICATION_ROOT: '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME: 'session'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN: None
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH: None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY: True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE: False
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE: None
SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST: True
MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH: None
SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT: datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200)
TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS: None
TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS: False
EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING: False
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME: 'http'
JSON_AS_ASCII: True
JSON_SORT_KEYS: '********'
JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR: False
JSONIFY_MIMETYPE: 'application/json'
TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD: None
MAX_COOKIE_SIZE: 4093
worker_max_tasks_per_child: 2
timezone: 'UTC'
result_extended: True
broker_heartbeat: 0
worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss: True
worker_deduplicate_successful_tasks: True
```

How can I make max-task-per-child restart workers after completing the specified number of tasks?

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.